# Titlepage dissertation help

Tags: titles

I've been trying to figure out how to fix my dissertation titlepage but it's driving me nuts!! I need to produce an output exactly like this (sorry for dividing the whole pic):[image]

[image]

In the first black box a university logo should appear and in the second the university name. Then below where it says "candidato" there's going to be my name and my student number, where it says "relatore" my teacher's name.
I'm working in report-ambient.. any help would be great!!

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.42 \textwidth] {logo}\\
    \vspace{7 em}
    { \text{University}}\\
    \vspace{1 em}
    { \text{Faculty}}\\
    { \text{type of degree}}\\
    \vspace{4em}
    {\text{Thesis type}}\\
    \vspace{4em}
    {\huge \textbf{title}}\\
    \vspace{4 em}
    {\text{Candidate:}}\\
    {\large\textbf{Myname}}\\
    {\text{mynumber}}\\        \vspace{4 em}
    {\text{teachername:}}\\       
    {\large\textbf{\textit{Prof.} name}}\\          
    \vspace{4em}
    {\text{year}}\\
    {\text{date}}\\
\end{center}
```

Which is nothing like the one above. It has to be exactly like that one: with the two lines and same architecture. I'd rather keep the report ambient to avoid other issues with the rest. Also I tried the `frontespizio` package but it's not working.

Comment: Welcome! Please post the code you've got so far or, at least give us a minimal document with your class and the textual content of the page. Also, be sure to include any *relevant* packages (not all of your packages!) e.g. if you are using a package to change the paper size, that would obviously be relevant.

Comment: Welcome, for a start you can have a look at [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993) and a few more examples at https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepages

Comment: Also, if your class is really `report-ambient`, we'd need a link if you're stuck.

Comment: @cfr Concerning the class, use stadard `report` or `article` or whatever and include the titlepage using `pdfpages`.  I find that to be much more simple than fixing margin stuff with geometry. There are strange things out there.

Comment: Johnny, which university is this in particular? Are there any specifics publicly available?

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes. I agree. But presumably the OP is using some class to create the title page itself. And if, say, A4 is required, you need something like `geometry` in the code for creating the title page. As you say, it need not matter what the main `.tex` file uses. But it does matter what e.g. `my-titlepage.tex` uses.

Comment: Have a look at the  [`frontespizio`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/frontespizio) package: it has a default layout similar to your needs, but it can be customized.

Comment: Still open questions: Name of the university? Any official specs concerning margins, fonts etc? Working with just a visual is pretty hard.

Comment: Have you asked this question to your university directly? It seems that if you would have to use this template, it must be in existence already.

Comment: The original has surely been produced with the `frontespizio` package. The documentation is in Italian.

Comment: @egreg I think the author of package `frontespizio` might be able to answer. Can you give him a short ping?

Comment: @Johannes_B I seem to know that author, I'll ask him.

Answer (score 4):

With the package `frontespizio` it's really easy.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{frontespizio}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontespizio}
\Universita{Roccacannuccia}
\Facolta{Scienze Matematiche, Fisiche e Naturali}
\Corso[Laurea triennale]{Fisica}
\Titolo{La fase di Berry}
\Candidato[12345]{C. Andidato}
\Relatore{Prof.\ R. E. Latore}
\Annoaccademico{2014--2015}
\Logo{../duck}
\end{frontespizio}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduzione}

Eccetera

\end{document}
```

If this document is called `fasediberry.tex`, running LaTeX on it will also produce a file called `fasediberry-frn.tex`. Run LaTeX over this one and rerun LaTeX on the main document.

It's not necessary to run LaTeX over `fasediberry-frn.tex` each time, just when the file has not yet been created or the contents of the `frontespizio` environment has changed.

If you know and use `arara`, the directive

```
arara: frontespizio
```

will do all the work for you.

[image]

Comment: :-) Shukraan. Ana majnun.

Answer (score 0):

I used `lualatex`, but you can change it to `pdflatex` ( `{fontspec}`-> `[T1]{fontenc}`. The titlepage has another layout:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{-4cm}\enlargethispage{3cm}
\hspace*{-2cm}\begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr\textheight+6cm]{17cm}\centering\sffamily
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{tiger}

\large\textbf{Università degli Sudi Roccacannuccia}

\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

\MakeUppercase{Facolta Scienze Matematiche, Fisiche e Naturali}

Corso di Laurea triennale in Fisica

\vfill\huge\bfseries La fase di Berry

\vfill\normalsize\normalfont
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
Candidato:\\
C. Andidato\\
Matricola 12345
\end{tabular}
\hfill%
\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}}
Relatore:\\
Prof. R.\,E. Latore
\end{tabular}

\vfill
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

Anno Accademico 2014--2015
\end{minipage}
\end{titlepage}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents    
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduzione}
Eccetera

\end{document}
```

[image]